# How is the Gastner-Newman equation implemented to create value-by-area cartograms?

Tags: linear-algebra, fluid-dynamics, nonlinear-programming, diffusion, differential-equations

There is a [paper](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~mejn/papers/geocomp.pdf) called "Density-equalizing map projections: Diffusion-based algorithm and applications" by Michael T. Gastner and M. E. J. Newman, which explains their algorithm (which is based in diffusion equations) for generating value-by-area cartograms.

While it explains the theoretical side of the mathematics involved with their algorithm, it doesn't explain how they actually implemented it. I tried to piece it together by looking at the source code from [cart](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~mejn/cart/), but I don't have the programming knowledge (it's written in c, which I don't know) required to understand it.

If anyone has at least a decent understanding of it and can explain the steps needed to create a cartogram using their algorithm, that would be greatly appreciated. Otherwise, if you have other helpful resources on the topic, those would be good too.

Comment: In the paper, what is the equation to be solved?

Comment: For density-based diffusion, you are trying to solve for the velocity given the diffusion equation, and then integrate the velocity field to solve for the cumulative displacement of each point over a time interval.